# Calculating list items using jQuery .length

Tags: jquery, list

Good afternoon,

My problem here is that I need to calculate the children contained in an unordered list. I am currently trying to use the .length technique but it doesn't seem to work.

What I need this to do is calculate whether there are enough items in the list to display the hidden link in the menu.

### HTML

```
<ul class="locations_list">
    <a href="#"><h2>List item 1</h2></a>
    <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
    <li class="all_attractions"><a href="#">See more items..</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.all_attractions { display: none !important; }
```

### jQuery

```
var listLength = $('.locations_list').children().length();
if (listLength == 6) {
    $('.all_attractions').show();
}
```

Not 100% sure where I'm going wrong here. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is your first item not a `<li>`?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What doesn't work as expected? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Yeah it's telling me "
TypeError: $(...).children(...).length is not a function"

Comment: so remove brackets from length (see my answer)

Comment: Not getting a console error anymore, however it's not showing on the unordered lists with 6 items. Think it might be something to do with the css?

Comment: remove !important from CSS, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Avoid brackets in length

Change

```
var listLength = $('.locations_list').children().length();
```

to

```
var listLength = $('.locations_list').children().length;
```

and remove !important from CSS rule to make it sure it's visible after calling show()

```
.all_attractions { display: none; }
```

You need to remember that children() will take into account also tag

```
  <a href="#"><h2>List item 1</h2></a>
```

which you have as first child and as well

```
 <li class="all_attractions">
```

even though it's not visible.

Comment: Yeah I had included the anchor in the 6, as the 'See more..' is the 7th and last in each list. Thanks for your help.

Comment: in your HTML snippet 'locations_list' have 4 children so your condition when you are comparing it to 6 will not match anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try  `length`

```
var listLength = $('.locations_list li').length;
alert(listLength);
if (listLength == 6) {
    $('.all_attractions').show();
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1482/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.locations_list').find('li').length == 6) {
    $('.all_attractions').show();
}
```

Comment: length is a property, not a function.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `hide()` - he hides it in css

Answer (score 0):

your listLength  is 4, .children() gives the handle of immediate childrens.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lenList = $('.locations_list > li').length;
if (lenList == 6) {
    $('.all_attractions').show();
}
```